# Check if NgControl is required

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, primeng, angular-forms

I've got several custom components that wrap PrimeNG components for various reasons. Some instances of my components are used in reactive forms, and the field's "requirement" is set using `Validators.required` validator.

PrimeNG components provide a `required` attribute.

How can I inspect my component's NgControl for the required validator?  There is `.disabled` and `.invalid`, but `.invalid` could mean anything.

Here I what I'm using now, which works for dropdowns, but would be incorrect for any other type of input.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  
  @Input()
  public disabled: boolean
  @Input()
  public required: boolean

  constructor(
        @Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl
  ) {
        if (this.ngControl != null) {
            this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.ngControl) {
            this.required = this.ngControl.invalid;
            this.disabled = this.ngControl.disabled;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to check if the control has a `required` validator or not like the following:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.ngControl) {
      this.required = this.hasRequiredValidator(this.ngControl.control);
      this.disabled = this.ngControl.disabled;
    }
  }

  hasRequiredValidator(control: AbstractControl): boolean {
    if (control.validator) {
      const validator = control.validator({} as AbstractControl);
      if (validator && validator.required) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

**From Angular 12.2.0**, to check if the NgControl has the `required` validator or not, we can use the [AbstractControl.hasValidator()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#hasvalidator) API which has been introduced in Angular 12.2.0 (Like how MatInput [shows required asterisk when using required validator](https://github.com/crisbeto/material2/blob/4b588d181b18beb74df0560318b129aea1036a63/src/material/input/input.ts#L178))

```js
  constructor(@Optional() @Self() private ngControl: NgControl) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.ngControl) {
      this.required = this.ngControl?.control?.hasValidator(Validators.required);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The `.validator` property is null.  Perhaps I'm injecting the wrong class/interface in the constructor.  I know for a fact the FormControl has `Validators.required`.

Comment: make sure that you passed `this.ngControl.control` not `this.ngControl` only.

Comment: I completely missed that.  Nice catch!  Thank you very much for this answer.  Works perfectly.

Comment: One thing I just realized is that `this.disabled = this.ngControl.disabled;` is completely unnecessary, as the `disabled` property is set on my component when the FormControl is disabled.

Comment: Ok, I added it in case you need it for any. Thanks.